# How to insert big HTML block in Javascript? Django JS

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have custom.js file in my django website. I need to create django - div in .js

> catalog.html

```
                <div class="row px-3" id="products-section">

                       #-----------------
                       # This block should be placed from js
                       #-----------------
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <article class="post post-medium border-0 pb-0 mb-5">
                                <div class="post-image">
                                    <a href="{% url 'product' product.url %}">
                                        <img src="media/{{product.img}}" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-no-borders rounded-0" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                       #-----------------
                       # End block
                       #-----------------

                </div>
```

> custom.js

```
var parent_div = document.getElementById("products-section");
product_node.innerHTML = "Big html block here";
parent_div.append(product_node);
```

How i can add so big block? And also i need to replace django variables by js variables in this block.

I need to replace django tags with javascript variables in my html block:

```
{% url 'product' product.url %}
img src="media/{{product.img}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it while using the html from string or read from file and then parse it twth cars and set in the innerHTML

```js
var parent_div = document.getElementById("products-section");
parent_div.innerHTML = `<div class="col-sm-4">
                            <article class="post post-medium border-0 pb-0 mb-5">
                                <div class="post-image">
                                    <a href="{% url 'product' product.url %}">
                                        <img src="media/{{product.img}}" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-no-borders rounded-0" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="post-content">
                                    <h2 class="font-weight-semibold text-5 line-height-6 mt-3 mb-2"><a href="{% url 'product' product.url_dop %}">{{product.name}}</a></h2>

                                    <p>{{product.description}}</p>

                                    <div class="post-meta">
                                        <span><i class="far fa-user"></i> by <a href="{% url 'brandpage' product.manufacturer_url %}">{{product.manufacturer_name}}</a> </span>
                                        <span class="d-block mt-2"><a href="{% url 'product' product.url %}" class="btn btn-xs btn-light text-1 text-uppercase">Подробнее</a></span>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>`
```

Comment: you can use ${jscode} 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals